# Avoiding database information on Uris

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, uri

Up until now, in my MVC applications, every time I wanted to get a resource I would include the database id in the URI.

**Example**: Imagine an application that have products, one of those products has the id 1, I could access the product details on the uri `products/1`

However this may be a issue, imagining that the id could change. Even if you argue that id is the primary key and it wouldn't change, users could still gain knowledge that 1 was in fact the product id and it is used to access the database. Could this possibly may come a security issue?
Despite of this, there is a dependency between the uri and how the database is structured.

(How) can I make a uri that isn't database dependent and still access that resource?

Comment: `users could still gain knowledge` : i don't think it is an  issue becuase user can not do anything with only product `id`.

Comment: IMOHO, It's only a "bad" thing to expose keys if they *can* be used in a malicious manner. For instance, it would be *very bad* to use an ID for an unprotected "account review" URI, e.g. where one can "guess" the access-point to information that should be restricted. However, as SO shows, there is nothing inherently wrong with exposing an ID (the question ID) along with a "pretty" identifier.

Comment: Also, as far as URI validity, there is no difference if an Auto-increment ID Key changes, a GUID Key changes, or if a Surrogate Key changes - it will still result in invalidating the previous URL if said Key was embedded into the URL to look-up a particular piece of information.

Comment: @user2864740 It was wise to point out SO as an example where ids are used to access data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a key field to the DB table(s) which is unique. When you look up the data select your rows by that field instead of the ID. No, this really isn't any more secure but it is easy to do if you'd like to. One reason to do this which is valid is for pretty URLs.

UPDATE:

Putting any feature on a website is inherently less secure than not putting it there. You are basically asking, 'Is it less secure to provide the ability to reference specific items in my DB from the web?'. The answer to that is yes but that doesn't mean that you shouldn't do it. It means that if you want to do it you'll need to be careful and make sure that your site is secure. Does it know that the person trying to access that resource is who they claim they are? If it does and if we've decided that means they should get access then we can say it is secure. The ability to access a resource is a feature; not a security hole.

Comment: do you think that user can do anything by knowing actual product `id`?

Comment: The problem is that uri is still related on how database is structured in your solution. Now I just could access the database by the key or by the id...

Comment: @BrunoCosta Another benefit of my solution is that now you can rename that field data all you want and the table won't need re-indexed. Just the one index will refresh.